# how to stub a property out using rhino for unit testing

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

Someone shoot me as I can't see what I'm missing but the inner property of my stubbed object is null which is breaking my tests.

Many Thanks,
James

**CommandService**

```
public void Create()
{
    var risk = _queryService.GetRisk(creatable.HeaderId);

    if(risk.HeaderId != null)  // HeaderId IS NULL??
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

**QueryService**

```
public Risk GetRisk(int headerId)
{
    return _repository.GetRisk(headerId);
}
```

**Unit test**

```
[TestInitialize]
public void SetUp()
{
  _mockRepository = new MockRepository();
  _queryService = _mockRepository.Stub<IQueryService>();
  _commandService = new CoreCommandService(_queryService);
}

public void MyTest()
{
   var runRisk = new RunRisk { HeaderId = 10 };

   _queryService.Stub(x => x.GetRisk(199)).Repeat.Any().Return(runRisk);

   var result = _commandService.Create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

need to use the following to fix it.

```
MockRepository.GenerateMock<IQueryService>();
```